# Reverse scroll direction in plasma 5

Tags: kubuntu, kde, mouse-scroll, mouse-wheel, plasma-5

Recently upgraded to kde plasma 5, I have noticed that reverse scrolling does not work on plasma 5 windows such as the control panel or application launcher while it works in other apps. Is there a way to configure this as it is very annoying. Reverse scrolling is already enabled in mouse settings.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This was an answer for Ubuntu derivatives in the 16.04 LTS generation. It does not apply anymore.

```
apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

Then restart Xorg (Logging out and logging back in should do it. If not, logging out, restarting sddm, and logging back in should do the trick)

You can also explicitly configure the libinput device to use NaturalScrolling. But I went with the first route and all was good.

Comment: Better late than never.

Comment: -100 This command just disabled my keyboard!